# Missing option for "Content Importer" in XNA (trying to import video)

Tags: video, xna

http://klucher.com/files/media/image/WindowsLiveWriter/VideoSupportinXNAGameStudio3.1_8E34/image_2.png

I don't have the option "WMV Video File - XNA Framework".

The video I'm importing is in WMV format and was encoded using Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 with the settings set to the predefined "VC-1 Xbox 360 HD 720p" so I don't think there's anything wrong with the video... DRM is not enabled.

Some other guy had this problem too but he never found a solution (or he did but didn't bother to post it) - http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/51297/310710.aspx

And yes I'm on XNA 3.1 and the video is put in a folder called "Videos" in the HighResolutionContent folder.

I have no idea what to do now! Please if anyone has any idea on how I should proceed, help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you add a reference to your Content Project for:
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.VideoImporters

Hope that helps.

Comment: By Jove you've got it! Thank you so much, that did the trick. For anyone else having the same problem - make sure you add the reference to the CONTENT Project.

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall game studio 3.1. because if everything was installed correctly, that content importer (which is part of the framework now) would be available.

The only other thing I can suggest (but it's a stretch) is, are you sure that your video file has a .wmv extension?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering...

Yes, it does have .wmv extension and I've actually just tried it on a different computer with Visual Studio and XNA 3.1 but it still doesn't have the option! Am I missing something?