# Unable to add Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline in Visual C# 2010 Express, Windows 7?

Tags: c#, xna, pipeline

I'm having trouble find the image file I have loaded into Visual C# 2010 Express when I compile my code.

Based on the answer here:
[Missing option for "Content Importer" in XNA (trying to import video)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862381/missing-option-for-content-importer-in-xna-trying-to-import-video)
I'm trying to add a reference to Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline, but it's not an option available in the Add Reference section.

As such, the Content Importer and Content Processor fields mentioned here are not showing up:
[xna 4.0 and loading images fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871320/xna-4-0-and-loading-images-fails)

The code crashes whenever I try to load a .jpg, .tga, or .png as a texture.

Where can I find the reference, or is there some way to get around it?

Comment: What version of XNA is your project targeting? If applicable, switch to the regular version of 4.0 (not Client).

Answer (score 2):

A very late answer, but hopefully someone still finds it useful:

To be able to use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline, you need to set the target framework of your project to `.NET Framework 4`, not `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` as seems to be the default. You can do this under the properties of your project.